# Reduce an array to a single value with Combine

Tags: swift, combine

How would I use swift combine to get the key of the first TrailVideo object who's site is "YouTube". I feel like I need a flatMap somewhere but I'm not entirely sure.

```
struct TrailerVideoResult: Codable {
   let results : [TrailerVideo]
}

struct TrailerVideo: Codable {
    let key: String
    let site: String
}

class Testing{
    //Should output the key of the first TrailVideo object who's site is "YouTube"

    func getYoutubeKey()-> AnyPublisher<String, Error>{
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "")!)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: TrailerVideoResult.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map(\.results)
            .map(\.sites)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: `.map` to results, `.filter` on the `site` value, `map` to the key, done

Answer (score 3):

You may use `compactMap` if you aren't concerned with errors (ie. if filtered `results` variable is empty):

```
class Testing {
    func getYoutubeKey() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "")!)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: TrailerVideoResult.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .map(\.results)
            .compactMap { $0.first { $0.site == "YouTube" }?.key }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Or if you want to provide a default value you can replace:

```
.compactMap { $0.first { $0.site == "YouTube" }?.key }
```

with:

```
.map { $0.first { $0.site == "YouTube" }?.key ?? "default" }
```

Comment: Close but this will only look at the first result. I ended up having to map over results to get the sites then grab the first where site == "YouTube"

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon No, it starts searching the whole array but returns immediately after the *first* object matching the criteria is found. If you're concerned about the use of `first(where:)` you can use `filter` + `first` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Sorry, I’m still finding combine to be a bit tricky. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to map over results to get the sites then grab the first where site == "YouTube". Thanks to @DonnyWals on Twitter for the help.

```
class Testing{
    //Should output the key of the first TrailVideo object who's site is "YouTube"
    func getYoutubeKey()-> AnyPublisher<String, Error>{
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "")!)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: TrailerVideoResult.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap{
               $0.results.first(where: {$0.site == "YouTube"}).map(\.key)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: And now you've basically re-implemented my answer :)

Comment: @pawello2222 You’re absolutely correct. I’ve upvoted you as the correct answer! Sorry about that.